# making this function thread safe while maintaining recursivity

Tags: c++, c, recursion

How do I make this function thread safe while maintaining the recursive nature of the code?

```
int foo(char *p)
 {
  static int i = 0;
   if (*p == '\0') return i;
   i++;
 return foo(p+1);
}
```

Comment: Pass `i` as a second argument. But: Why???

Comment: could be a little more elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: [What is this thing you call Thread-Safe - Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: Well... thread safe clearly does not mean multiple threads updating the static variable...

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int foo(char* p, int start)
{
    if (*p == 0) return start;
    return foo(p+1, start+1);
}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "HI THERE";

    cout << foo(test, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has the extra advantage of allowing tail-recursion optimizations (i.e. the function calls can be transformed to a loop)

Comment: This isn't equivalent though as `i` gets reset each call.

Comment: @Pubby Not equivalent but probably what the OP really wants. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you could use [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local):

```
int foo(char *p)
{
  thread_local int i = 0;
  if (*p == '\0') return i;
  i++;
  return foo(p+1);
}
```

The function is, I hope, just an example as `i=0` will be executed only once (in your example) and once *per thread* in my example.

Older compilers sometimes support `static __thread` as a pre-C++11-alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo(char *p, int i = 0)
{
    if(*p == '\0')
        return i;
    return foo(p+1, i+1);
}
```

Recursion is nice and all, but it can be less efficient than a loop if stack frames are created. It's the easiest way to cause a stack overflow. I would recommend getting rid of it. The following is simpler and likely faster:

```
int foo(char *p)
{
    return strlen(p);
}
```

Or better yet, just call [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) directly and get rid of `foo`.

Note that this is pretty unsafe. What if a `'\0'` doesn't come? You'll just read on into who knows what...

Comment: +1 for the default value for `i`. But `strlen` is just as "unsafe" (except that it won't blow the stack on super-long strings) ... that the `p` argument points to a NUL-terminated string is a (untestable) pre-condition.

Comment: @user2115365 `strlen` is in a generic library... The C++ standard library. And it works.